# How to send firebase notifications using django-admin panel or Admin account?

Tags: python, django, firebase, django-admin

I'm developing an android app in client side and django admin panel in server side. What I need to do is sending firebase notifications to single or all users, I have already registered android app to firebase .

I know I should use django-fcm .

I need a recommendation or any suggestion to make it right.

Can I have a page to send notifications to users that only admin account can access to it?

Any suggestions will be helpful.

I searched a lot, but not found anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [fcm_django](https://fcm-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for your requirement

**Notification to send for all users**

```
from fcm_django.models import FCMDevice

device = FCMDevice.objects.all()

device.send_message(title="Title", body="Message", icon=..., data={"test": "test"})
```

Notification to send for single user

```
from fcm_django.models import FCMDevice

device = FCMDevice.objects.get(user=user_id)

device.send_message(title="Title", body="Message", icon=..., data={"test": "test"})
```

In admin.py

```
class YourModel(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        try:

            user_instance = User.objects.get(id=obj.user.id)

            # above fcm code

        except Exception as e:

            print(e.args)
            pass

        super(YourModel, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)

admin.site.register(YourModel,YourModelAdmin)
```

simply follow the [docs](https://fcm-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Where should i put this code ? and How i Implement FCMDevice model ?

Comment: can i send push notifications in situations like admin add a record in database ?

Comment: django_fcm will create all the required models for you

Comment: yes why not just add above code after record is inserted

Comment: Execuse me , Where should i put this code ? i'm using django admin panel , where to find insert function in admin panel ?

Comment: you need to extend admin method to add your custom code in it

Comment: thanks to you , i will try this solution , and tell you the result .

Comment: What is this YourModel and YourModelAdmin ? think that i have a table with products in it , and i want to send a notification to users when a new product is inserted in database ? i have a model named Products and I Have ProductsAdmin class in Admin.py . what can i do for it ? sorry if i dont understand exactly what you say , i'm new to django .

Comment: Sorry ,What should i do ?

Comment: User sends the fcm token to server and this fcm is stored in users table with name of token .

Comment: just go through the document

Comment: Thanks a lot , now i can send test notifications from django-admin panel , sorry to ask you a again , i didnt understand What Model ,YourModel is , and what is the function save_model do

Comment: if you say to me what is YourModel and YourModelAdmin , i will be very thanksfull to you